# Component bundles

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I'd like to create components which have a similar structure (all of them having a controller class, a XIB file and language resources). I've figured I could use bundles for this purpose. However, it seems there are some limitations on iOS (for example you cannot use loadable bundles which pretty much correspond to what I'd like to do). For me this would be important for better organisation/packaging of code and better reusability provided by such components.

Does anyone have a good pointer to an arcticle, etc dealing with similar issues?

Comment: As the two down votes show it may be a bit too general question. Yes, for sure, but I'd need some general advise - I haven't found anything usable so far. I'd like to somehow package stuff (code and resources) together such that it creates a new namespace. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can wait for iOS8 this is made easier as you can now use Frameworks, which are an easier way of bundling code and resources.

These are still tied to the app at build time, so you can't use them for plug-ins at run time, but it should make sharing code and resources between projects simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm targeting iOS 8, I will have a good look at Frameworks then.

Comment: There are WWDC14 videos on Xcode and Frameworks that you should have a look at.